# jquery AJAX function issue

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to run a function that executes a spinner while a PHP script is loading and also refreshes a PHP file that counts the number of rows inserted to show the script's progress.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  // start spinner on button click
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(spinner) {
    $("#spinner").show();
  });

  // refresh progress script and output to #content div
  function updateProgress(){
    $('#content').load('progress.php');
  }

  myTimer = setInterval( "updateProgress()", 2000 );

  // Execute the primary function
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#driver").click(function(event){
      $('#stage').load('execute.php');
    });
  });

  // hide spinner and content div when finished
  $(document).ajaxStop(function(spinner) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    $("#spinner").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#content").fadeOut("fast");
  });
</script>
```

Right now the updateProgress() function starts after the first interval is over even if the button hasn't been pushed, so I'm assuming I have to tie it in with the spinner function but I'm just not entirely sure how to make that work.

EDIT: Here's the HTML that displays the button and the div's:

```
<div id="stage">
Click to Import New Data into AssetData Table
   <p>
      <div id="spinner"><img src="/images/spinner.gif" alt="Loading..."></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <p>
      <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" onClick="this.disabled=true;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. Load page with button. When you push button file `execute.php` should upload.
2. After user push button, spinner appearing and browser starts make ajax request to `progress.php`.
3. When `execute.php` uploaded, spinner disappears, progress results disappears.

jQuery code below doing this:

```
var myTimer;

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Execute the primary function
    $("#driver").click(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139',
            success: function (data) {
                //$("#someField").html(data); // you put result of executting `execute.php` into #someField field by uncommenting this string
                $("#spinner").toggle();
                $("#content").fadeOut("fast");
                clearInterval(myTimer);
            },
            error: function (bob) {
                // show error
                console.log('get error');
                clearInterval(myTimer);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                myTimer = setInterval(function () {
                    /* // uncomment this when you will use it with real files and server
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'progress.php',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#content").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                    */

                    $("#content").append("progress data<br>");
                    console.log('progress executed');
                }, 1); // change delay, when you work with real files and server
                $("#spinner").toggle();

                console.log('ajaxSend handler executed');
            }
        });
        console.log('main function executed');
    });

});
```

Look [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h8eU7/85/) example (this example for code above), please.

Now, this code do all what you need. Right?

Don't forget to uncomment some lines (ajax requests), change intervals, remove debug outputs (line 29, for example) etc.

Notice (and change it, when you will use my code) `url` field of `execute.php` ajax-requst. I had used weather api (just for example, you musth change it to `progress.php` because download this data takes some time, so you can see results. Remove weather url and put url to `progress.php`.

Also, you can check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h8eU7/95/) example. Code is tided up and this version allows to load file and after that load another. And after that load another. + now `myTimer`+`setInterval`+`function progress` synergizes better, I suppose.

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The spinner isn't the problem, that works fine.  My issue is the updateProgress function executes after the delay runs out before the button is even pushed & outputs the result from the progress.php query immediately after the first setInterval time runs out. 

However, if I push the button right away, the spinner runs, it counts and outputs the rows, and then finishes when the PHP file (execute.php) is done.

Needless to say I'm just trying to figure out how to get that function to wait until the button is pushed before executing. That's my biggest dilemma right now.

Comment: @user3566452 I totally updated my answer. I think now I answered your question.

Comment: Appreciate the help.  Unfortunately the progress.php isn't showing when the execute.php is running.

Here's the remainder of the code in the HTML:

'code'<div id="stage">
 Click to Import New Data into AssetData Table
          <p>
          <div id="spinner"><img src="/administration/images/spinner.gif" alt="Loading..."></div>
          <div id="content"></div>
          <p>
          <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" onClick="this.disabled=true;">
   </div>

Comment: Let me try that again. Unfortunately the progress.php isn't showing when the execute.php is running.  I just added the remaining HTML with my original code to make it easier to look at, so hopefully that helps.

Comment: Mhm... whaaaat??? Just explain me what you want to achieve lol. Example: 1. Push button and send ajax request 2. Start spinner on push button 3. Stop spinner when script executed and data received. (btw, this is what my script above do)

Comment: Sorry :)  When I push the button, I want the spinner to appear and the result to begin to be echoed in the #content div from progress.php, which is querying the number of rows being inserted by the execute.php script, which is importing data.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: What exactly you do in `execute.php`? Why such structure? What exactly you want to achieve? Add photos? Send mails? Insert some values?

Comment: execute.php imports an xml file and inserts the data into the database.  It's a relatively large file and takes about a minute or two to import.

All I want to achieve is to have spinner and progress.php show (with progress.php refreshed every 5-10 seconds or so to show the progress into the #content div) and then have both the spinner disappear and the refreshing to stop when the script is done.

Comment: @user3566452 I updated my code. Now it do all, what you asked about.